# Custom file attribute in FAT32 and NTFS

Tags: c++, filesystems, ntfs, fat32, file-attributes

I want the ability add custom property/tag to a file  with any file extension.
For example file.txt or file.pdf or file.jpg should all store and carry properties like 'custom tag'.
The tag should be stored with the file itself. Such that if it is transferred from NTFS file system to usb-disk with FAT32 file system and vice-versa it retains the tag.

How do I make this possible using c++?
Any application that already does this?

Thank you

Comment: FAT32 doesn't support this, period.

Comment: You're of course free to add a `file.pdf.customtags` file alongside `file.pdf`, and have your own copy program copy the two files in parallel. The problem you'll face is that every other program that copies files will not play by your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support both NTFS and FAT32 (and maybe more), you'd probably be fine with extended attributes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Comment: Extended file attributes in NTFS file system refers to NTFS File Streams, but in FAT32 there is no way to add custom attribute in user-mode, since attribute will be ignored by SetFileAttributeW.